# Load yaml files with wildcard in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyyaml

I want to open all *.yaml files in a folder and load them with PyYaml. Each file contains one yaml document.
My recent code fragment:

```
stream = open("conf.d/*.yaml", 'r')
config = yaml.load_all(stream)
```

This fails, as yaml.open obviously can't work with wildcards:

```
stream = open("conf.d/*.yaml", 'r')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'conf.d/*.yaml'
```

How is the correct way to archive this goal?

Answer (score 2):

In Python 2.5+ can use the `glob` module to expand the wildcard into a list of filenames.

```
>>> import glob
>>> a = glob.glob("*.yaml")
>>> print a
['test1.yaml', 'test2.yaml', 'test3.yaml']
```

You can then feed it to an iterator like `map()` to generate a list of PyYAML configuration generators.

```
>>> import yaml
>>> import glob
>>> configs = map(lambda x: yaml.load_all(open(x)), glob.glob("*.yaml"))
>>> print configs
[<generator object load_all at 0x1078bfe10>, <generator object load_all at 0x1078bfd20>, <generator object load_all at 0x1078bfb90>]
>>> for config in configs:
...     for item in config:
...         print item
... 
{'date': datetime.date(2015, 2, 27), 'customer': {'given': 'Gordon', 'family': 'Jeff'}, 'location': 'Target'}
{'date': datetime.date(2015, 2, 25), 'customer': {'given': 'Earnhardt', 'family': 'Dale'}, 'location': 'Walmart'}
{'date': datetime.date(2015, 2, 23), 'customer': {'given': 'Petty', 'family': 'Richard'}, 'location': 'Target'}
```

Comment: This solves the problem with the wildcard itself, but open needs a string or a stream as input.

Comment: @Dakkar Updated to iterate over the filenames and generate configurations. Keep in mind that `yaml.load_all` only takes a single stream or string. If you need a single combined configuration you could try reading the contents of the `*.yaml` files and concatenating them into a single string object to feed into `load_all`. That does have the undesired effect of overwriting duplicate YAML keys.